# Compare a string to CMD output using Java

Tags: java, cmd, java.util.scanner, processbuilder

I'm trying to create a method that returns true or false based off of the result from sfc /scannow but for some reason the string comparison always returns false even though it prints as exactly what I'm comparing it to. Any ideas?

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "sfc /scannow");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
Scanner sn = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while (sn.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sn.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.")) {
        isHealthy = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(isHealthy == true) {
    return true;
}
else if(isHealthy == false) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the output?

Comment: You do of course realize that to run `sfc` within a command window (cmd.exe) that command window must be Run as Administrator.

Comment: @AdrianRusso 
```B e g i n n i n g   s y s t e m   s c a n .     T h i s   p r o c e s s   w i l l   t a k e   s o m e   t i m e . 
 
 
 
 
 
 B e g i n n i n g   v e r i f i c a t i o n   p h a s e   o f   s y s t e m   s c a n . 
 
 
 
 V e r i f i c a t i o n   0 %   c o m p l e t e . 
 .... 
 V e r i f i c a t i o n   1 0 0 %   c o m p l e t e . 
 
 
 
W i n d o w s   R e s o u r c e   P r o t e c t i o n   d i d   n o t   f i n d   a n y   i n t e g r i t y   v i o l a t i o n s .```

Comment: The information above should be in your question, not in comments. All important question related information should be in the question itself. Please [edit] your question. Also please check out the [help] and the [ask].

Comment: Looks like `new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)` would be needed.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with option `/c` just to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\sfc.exe` with option `/scannow` using `ProcessBuilder` of Java. `ProcessBuilder` uses on Windows function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with structure [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow). `cmd.exe` uses exactly the same function and the same structure to run `sfc.exe` which outputs in Unicode (UTF-16 LE).

Comment: Use in Java code [system.getenv("SystemRoot")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-) to get the string value of this predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows), concatenate this string with `"\\System32\\sfc.exe"` and run this executable with `ProcessBuilder` with option `/scannow` and capture the Unicode output.

Answer (score -1):

In this case your are comparing Objects and not always the value itself, so you'll be good checking using contentEquals:

```
...
if(line.contentEquals("What Do you want to verify")) { condition }
```

Let me know if this works for you!

The String#equals() not only compares the String's contents, but also checks if the other object is also an instance of a String . The String#contentEquals() only compares the contents (the character sequence) and does not check if the other object is also an instance of String

Comment: This still return false when compared to the string for some reason

Comment: Before the if, what are the results with System.out.println(line);?